# Agent unable to perform upload to artifact feed because agent identity it uses lacks authorization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

This is a problem that has already been discussed elsewhere on Stack Overflow and other forums; I tried to apply the suggested solutions, but without success. I have defined a simple 'Hello World' project that compiles a class, generates a JAR file, and uploads it to an artifact repository (https://github.com/ebomitali/azure-devops-mvn-deploy). As per the instructions found in various places, it is necessary to add the build services identity whose full name is '<project name> Build Services (<organization name>)' as a Collaborator. This works correctly with Project A in Organization A, but in my case, it fails for every pipeline defined in Project B.

The message is: ... status: 403 Forbidden - User 'a68e4335e-...' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'...

The id of the agent identity is different from the identity of the '<project name> Build Services (<organization name>)'.  Based on documentation found on the internet, these two identities are automatically created by the system. Additionally, these two identities should be connected so whenever I add or take out something from '<project name> Build Services (<organization name>)', the same happens to agent id. As mentioned, I got a project where it consistently fails, both with a Self Hosted Agent and an Azure Hosted Agent. Short of recreating the project from scratch, is there a way to manage these entities (reset them, delete them and recreat, or something else) to attempt to resolve the issue? Is there a way to query Azure DevOps to verify the actual permissions of these identities?

Answer (score 1):

The account `<project name> Build Services (<organization name>)` is project level build identity.

However, the identity(`a68e4335e-...`) in your error could be different, it could point to `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})` , the `<project B> build service account`(as project A is working， project B is not) or specific user. It depends on if you set the job authorization scope to be collection or project.

To make sure the account, you can use rest api [Identities - Read Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) with ID.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/identities?identityIds={identityIds}&api-version=7.0
```

[image]

On the feed setting, add the account above as the **contributor** role to fix the error. (if the identity points to a specific user, add the user)
[image]

You can find more details on the scoped identity on doc [Access repositories, artifacts, and other resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Hi, using your query example I verified that the identity is a Project Collection Build Service ([my organization]) identity. Please note that it was already added in feed settings as a contributor. I tried to remove it from feed settings and then add it again, nothing changed as I was getting the same 403 error.

Comment: Go to project settings-> check value for `Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines` setting. If it's toggled `off`, make sure `Project Collection Build serivce[org]` account has contributor on the feed. If it's toggled `ON`, make sure `<project name> Build Services (<organization name>)` has contributor role on the feed. I used same github [repo](https://github.com/ebomitali/azure-devops-mvn-deploy) and confirm it's working on my side. Did you put the project A and project B in same DevOps organization?

Comment: Hi, Project A and Project B are on the same organization. Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines setting. Is toggled off. I too used the same repo in Project A and Project B. In project A it works. IN project B it does not work. Moreover, every pipline in project B does not work. I checked the configuration in both project and was unable to notice any difference. Project B pipelines use Project Collection Build serivce[org]. Is there a way to tell which identity a pipeline is using? I would like to check pipeline of Project A (successful) is different.

Comment: The Identities are built-in type, depends on the setting above, you can check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities) which i mentioned before.  For your scenario, suggest to check the pom.xml in project B, is the DevOps feed name and url correct? In addition, if  every pipline in project B does not work, please create a new project C, clone the code from project A, will the pipeline in project C be working?

Comment: Hi @EvelinoBomitali, is there any update? let me know if you have any queries.